# What is the difference of BeforeAndAfter and BeforeAndAfterEach in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

Looking at documentation, the two seem very similar ([BeforeAndAfterEach](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.2/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfterEach.html) [BeforeAndAfter](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.2/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfter.html)). What is the core difference between them. What are the situations when one of them should be used over the other (and possibly the other wouldn't even work.)

Comment: The first one will be executed before and after each test, the second one will be executed before all tests and after all tests in that suite.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, that is not correct. From [BeforeAndAfter](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.2/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfter.html): Trait BeforeAndAfter offers one way to eliminate such code duplication: a before clause that will register code to be run before each test, and an after clause that will register code to be run after.

Comment: To clarify, I originally got confused with this at first, because the test I inherited and started to work on was missing a `super.beforeEach()` call in its `beforeEach()` implementation and I didn't notice that. Due to the missing `super` call nothing worked as expected and I started to wonder if it had something to do with the specific trait being used. But I think that this was a question that someone else might pose and now the great answer by @TomerShetah can be found by typing the question to google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `scalatest` documentation you can find all the info you need.

TL;DR: Both have the same functionality. `BeforeAndAfter` is more concise, while `BeforeAndAfterEach` is more stackable.

[`BeforeAndAfter` recommended usage](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/3.2.x-new/jvm/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfter.scala#L26):

> Use trait `BeforeAndAfter` when you need to perform the same side-effects before and/or after tests, rather than at the beginning or end of tests. Note: For more insight into where BeforeAndAfter fits into the big picture, see the Shared fixtures section in the documentation for your chosen style trait.

Should I use `BeforeAndAfter` or `BeforeAndAfterEach`? ([From `BeforeAndAfter` perspective](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/3.2.x-new/jvm/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfter.scala#L99))

> Although `BeforeAndAfter` provides a minimal-boilerplate way to execute code before and after tests, it isn't designed to enable stackable traits, because the order of execution would be non-obvious. If you want to factor out before and after code that is common to multiple test suites, you should use trait `BeforeAndAfterEach` instead.
>
> The advantage this trait has over BeforeAndAfterEach is that its syntax is more concise. The main disadvantage is that it is not stackable, whereas `BeforeAndAfterEach` is. I.e., you can write several traits that extend `BeforeAndAfterEach` and provide beforeEach methods that include a call to super.beforeEach, and mix them together in various combinations. By contrast, only one call to the before registration function is allowed in a suite or spec that mixes in BeforeAndAfter. In addition, `BeforeAndAfterEach` allows you to access the config map and test name via the TestData passed to its beforeEach and afterEach methods, whereas `BeforeAndAfter` gives you no access to the config map.

[`BeforeAndAfterEach` recommended usage](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/3.2.x-new/jvm/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfterEach.scala#L23):

> Use trait `BeforeAndAfterEach` when you want to stack traits that perform side-effects before and/or after tests, rather than at the beginning or end of tests. Note: For more insight into where `BeforeAndAfterEach` fits into the big picture, see the Shared fixtures section in the documentation for your chosen style trait.

Should I use `BeforeAndAfter` or `BeforeAndAfterEach`? ([From `BeforeAndAfterEach` perspective](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/3.2.x-new/jvm/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfterEach.scala#L111)):

> The main advantage of `BeforeAndAfterEach` over `BeforeAndAfter` is that `BeforeAndAfterEach`. enables trait stacking. The main disadvantage of `BeforeAndAfterEach` compared to BeforeAndAfter is that `BeforeAndAfterEach` requires more boilerplate. If you don't need trait stacking, use `BeforeAndAfter` instead of `BeforeAndAfterEach`. If you want to make use of test data (the test name, config map, etc.) in your beforeEach or afterEach method, use trait `BeforeAndAfterEachTestData` instead.

P.s. I see that there is a common mistake that one will execute for each test and the other won't. There is another trait for that called [`BeforeAndAfterAll`](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/3.2.x-new/jvm/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfterAll.scala).

Comment: Hi @Tomer Shetah  does it mean the same between "test suites" and "test class"? do you have a concret example for the 'beforeAndAfterEach' where it was implemented in more than 1 traits and then stacked them?

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggest
`BeforeAndAfter` will run once(at start and at the end) for a test class.
`BeforeAndAfterEach` will run before and after each test case in the class.

Use `BeforeAndAfter`: Suppose you want you create an in Memory database for the tests to run you will create it before running the test cases and then you will clear the memory after running all the test cases.

Use `BeforeAndAfterEach`: Suppose you have some cache value which requires different value for each test case to run, in that case you can change the value of that cache for before each test case and clear it after running a single test.

Comment: That is not correct. Run a simple test to find that out. Both will run before and after each test

Comment: @TomerShetah is correct. This answer doesn't clarify the key difference.